# Static method in Unittest not found - NoMethodError - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have some unit tests which try to test my API:

```
class ClassToBeTested

def self.something_first
    # Do Something
  end

  def self.something_second
    # Do Something
  end
end
```

I call them in the testing class then as following:

```
class MyTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test 'should get something_first' do
    assert ClassToBeTested.something_first
  end

  test 'should get something_second' do
    assert ClassToBeTested.something_second
  end
end
```

Which ends up throwing the following error:

> Error: MyTest#test_should_get_something_first: NoMethodError:
>   undefined method `something_first' for ClassToBeTested
>       test/services/my_test.rb:89:in`block in '
>
> bin/rails test test/services/my_test.rb:88

I tried around a lot but I can't find what the issue is.

Comment: Does instance's method work?

Comment: Didn't try yet, the class only has static methods

Comment: Let's try. Maybe it'll help to find out what's wrong

Comment: Okay I found out that one of the libraries we're using uses the same ClassName so he can't find the Method there, is there a way to avoid this?
I want it to point at my class.

Comment: You can just rename your class

Comment: "I found out that one of the libraries we're using uses the same ClassName" - I don't see why would it still not find methods defined by you. Redefining a class adds new methods to existing definition of class.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue I was faced was that a Library I was using had a class with the same name.

So my Unittest was calling this other class and not the class I defined, to solve this I added:

load 'ClassToBeTested.rb' in the header of the testing class.

A cleaner way probably is to define the ClassToBeTested in a Module and use the namespace to call it.